# how to post comment below the text box after clicking submit button?

Tags: php, html, css, forms

am trying to make a "Add your recipe" page in my website.. i have tried this form and it shows perfectly.. but how do i post the recipe below the form after clicking submit button according to the recipe format?

```
 <center>
   <form method="post">
    <div class='wrapperr'>
        <div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='container'>
        <div class='top'>
            <div class='logo'></div>
            <div class='gray close'></div>
        </div>

        <div class='content'>
            <ul class='section'>
                <li class='header'></li>
                <li class='item right-label'>
                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder='eg. Chocolate Chip  Cookies' id="title" class='shorter' />
                    <div class='picture-container'>
                        <div class='picture'></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class='item right-label'>
                    <label for="author">Author</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder='eg. Julia Child (optional)' id="author" class='shorter' />
                </li>
                <li class='item right-label'>
                    <label for="adapted">Adapted</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder='eg. The Joy of Cooking (optional)' id="adapted" class='shorter' />
                </li>
                <li class='item right-label'>
                    <label for="adapted-link">Adapt Link</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder='  (optional)' id="adapted-link" class='shorter' />
                    <input type="button" class="button green box-shadow" value="Select Image" id="picture" />
                </li>
                <li class='item spaced right-label'>
                    <label for="summary" id="summary-label">Description</label>
                    <textarea placeholder='eg. A delicious drop cookie  (optional)' id="summary"></textarea>
                </li>
                  <li class='item right-label'>
                    <label for="prep-time">Prep Time</label><input  type="text" placeholder="HH:MM (optional)" id="prep-time" class="time" />
                    <label for="cook-time">Cook Time</label><input type="text" placeholder="HH:MM (optional)" id="cook-time" class="time" />
                    <label for="total-time">Total Time</label><input type="text" placeholder="HH:MM (optional)" id="total-time" class="time" />
                </li>
                <li class='item right-label'>
                    <label for="servings">Serves</label><input type="text" placeholder="Amount (optional)" id="servings" class="amount" />
                    <label for="yields">Yields</label><input type="text" placeholder="Amount (optional)" id="yields" class="amount" />
                </li>
                <li class='header new'></li>
                <li class='item'>
                    <label for="ingredients">Ingredients</label>
                    <textarea placeholder="One ingredient per line, include subheaders by ending with a colon (eg. For the cake:)" id="ingredients" class='larger'></textarea>
                </li>
                <li class='item'>
                    <label for="directions">Directions</label>
                    <textarea placeholder="One direction per line, include subheaders by ending with a colon (eg. For the cake:)" id="directions" class='larger'></textarea>
                </li>
                <li class='item'>
                    <label for="notes">Notes</label>
                    <textarea placeholder="One note per line, include subheaders by ending with a colon (eg. Great tip:) (optional)" id="notes" class='larger'></textarea>
                </li>
                <li class='header new error-list' style="display: none"></li>
                <li class='new error-data' style="display: none">
                    <ul class='error-ul'>
                        <li class='error-title' style="display: none">Please enter a title for the recipe.</li>
                        <li class='error-adapted-link' style="display: none">Please enter a valid url.</li>
                        <li class='error-prep-time' style="display: none">Please enter a prep time using HH:MM such as <b>1:15</b> for an hour and fifteen minutes or <b>25</b> for 25 minutes.</li>
                        <li class='error-cook-time' style="display: none">Please enter a cook time using HH:MM such as <b>1:15</b> for an hour and fifteen minutes or <b>25</b> for 25 minutes.</li>
                        <li class='error-total-time' style="display: none">Please enter a total time using HH:MM such as <b>1:15</b> for an hour and fifteen minutes or <b>25</b> for 25 minutes.</li>
                        <li class='error-servings' style="display: none">Please enter a number for the serves amount such as <b>4</b> for a recipe that makes 4 servings.</li>
                        <li class='error-yields' style="display: none">Please enter a number for the yields amount such as <b>18</b> for a recipe that makes 18 cookies.</li>
                        <li class='error-ingredients' style="display: none">Please enter some ingredients for your recipe.</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class='new center'>
                    <input type="button" class='button green standard-button box-shadow' value='Save' id="save" />
                    <input type="button" class='button white standard-button box-shadow' value='Cancel' id="cancel" />
                    <div class='working'>
                        <div class='working-image'></div>
                        <div class='working-text'>Saving Recipe</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
           </div>
       </div>
        </div></center>`
```

Comment: I don't see any php code. Are you even receiving the POST? and saving it in database?

Comment: @Shank am sorry but i dont know how to write php for this.. and am not saving in database just posting below.. thanks you for the reply..

Comment: You can't do that without a database unless you use JavaScript for it. Do you know JavaScript?

Comment: @FahadUddin  thank you .. but.. how can i use JavaScript for this..?

Comment: @Fahad Uddin are you sure? I think you can post the form to an `iframe` using only php

Comment: @srav I suggest using PHP, as i assume you'll need to store the comment

Comment: @srav First you will need to learn how to [Post](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-post.html) Then storing the posted form in MySQL DB [Insert](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_multiple.asp)

Comment: And then [Display](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) the stored comment

Comment: @srav If you think it's too much work you can use 3rd party comment box, like [Disqus](https://disqus.com/features/). However you have no control for the forms.

Comment: You could use something like this:  action="MAILTO:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain" But you will be using the users email client. Use PHP

Comment: @Shank    thanks you so much guys.. i will use php and will try it. thanks a lot for the help.. :)

Comment: @DanielForbes I shall try that.. thank you.. :)

Comment: @fartagaintuxedo: I posted the link to the working demo. I haven't used a submit button though.

Comment: @Fahad Uddin i thought u meant only possible involving javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the link to the comments box made using HTML and JavaScrit. It doesn't work on the submit button but serves the purpose.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <textarea id="comment" placeholder="Say something..." /></textarea><br>
    <a href="#" onclick="postComment();">Post comment!</a>
</form>
<div id="comments">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.postComment=function()
{
var div = document.getElementById("comments");

div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML +"<br>"+ document.getElementById("comment").value;

}
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8ushhr5c/).

Comment: Thank you soo much.. i shall try this now.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a php file called 'Config.php'

```
class Config {
    public static function get($item){
    if(isset($_POST[$item])){
        return $_POST[$item];
    } else if(isset($_GET[$item])) {
        return $_GET[$item];
    }
    return '';
    }
}
```

then add a `require_once 'Config.php'` to your page with the form

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']){ // if user submits form
     echo Config::get('comments');
}
```

The function will check the form method, and return the $_POST or $_GET value. We then check if the user has submitted the form. Once they do, it will get the value and echo it to the page.

Comment: thank you soo much but i don't know how to use that code in my file..! am sorry..